# How to Join two tables and return all rows from both tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I have two tables. Users and Books, I want to join these two tables and return all rows for both tables. The common column in the is 'uid';

sql statement for books.

```
SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY TIME DESC;
```

From the above i get user_id 'uid' and use it in a separate query.

And for users.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '$uid';
```

I want to end up with something like the following instead of going in and out of the database from table.books and then table.users .

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
           echo $row[book_name];
           echo $row[user_firstname];
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get. Specifically, please note what kind of output you'd want if a certain user have more than one book.

Comment: "join these two tables and return all rows for both tables" & "something like" are not clear. Please give a [mre].  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look for funda of JOINs in database to learn about how to join two tables to retrieve specific data.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM books b 
INNER JOIN users u ON b.uid = u.uid 
ORDER BY b.TIME DESC;
```

Comment: `outer join` would be better

Comment: Ok this is now correct, one problem on my side, both tables have a column, 'Title', how do I get title from books and not the one from users. $row['title'] graps title from users and not the one from books.

Answer (score 2):

This is called FULL JOIN, you can implement it in MySql

```
SELECT *
FROM books AS b 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON b.uid = u.uid 

UNION

SELECT *
FROM books AS b 
RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON b.uid = u.uid
```

With order

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM books AS b 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON b.uid = u.uid 

    UNION

    SELECT *
    FROM books AS b 
    RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON b.uid = u.uid 
) t
ORDER BY t.TIME DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.*,b.* FROM books a INNER JOIN users b ON (a.id = b.uid)

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query for the all data from both tables without any filtration

```
select * from Users u,Books b where u.user_id=b.uid
```

if you given GROUP BY or any other Constrains then after the "Where" clause using the "and" marge the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

Use **Inner Join**

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.`user_firstname` FROM books t1
    JOIN users t2 ON t2.`uid` = t1.`uid`
```

Comment: I want to return all rows, not just book_name

Comment: on book you still only selecting `user_firstname`, it should be *.

Comment: from `users` table i am selecting only `user_firstname` . its your choice you can use `*`.

Answer (score -1):

This return all rows from books and users

```
SELECT * 
FROM books b 
FULL OUTER JOIN users u ON b.uid=u.uid;
```

Comment: ...syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN users u ON b.uid=u.uid' at line 3

Answer (score -1):

Select books.bookname,users.user_firstname from books join users on books.id=users.id

Comment: does not include all records from both